# Yarn throws error for dependent dependencies

Tags: npm, dependencies, yarnpkg

I'm getting below Yarn error.

> error moduleB@0.1.2: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "~0.10.22".

Below is my `package.json`

```
"engines": {
  "node": ">4.0.0"
}
"dependencies": {
  "moduleA": "^x.x.x"
}
```

moduleA has dependency

"dependencies": {
  "moduleB": "^3.3.3"
}

I tried for that `moduleB`.

```
npm show moduleB engines
{ node: '>=4.0.0 < 7.0.0' }
```

Any clue. much appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's because of *moduleB* package, I had the exact same issue with *svgutils*, looking at their source code on GitHub I found in the *package.json* the following:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "~0.10.22"
  }
```

You can create an issue for them or might as well fork the repo and make the necessary changes.